# How to block website so that it doesn't run via proxy

Tags: vpn, firewall, ip

Is there a way to ban adult websites?

A country blocks access to adult websites based on the IP address. The person still access those adult websites by using a proxy like "tor browser", "Psiphon" browser plugins "browsec", etc.

Is there a solution to ban access to adult websites even if the person uses a proxy?

Comment: are you try sauid (http://www.squid-cache.org/Download/) web filter

Comment: How users access the internet (i.e. through proxy server , through router only , through FW ....)

Comment: Simple solution, if you are already blocking access to adult sites, simply block access to known proxies or VPN services as well.

Comment: Oh yeah that's the real Tor meaning

Comment: @Ylearn *simple* might not be the best word. New proxy services pop up daily =/

Comment: @Eddie, I think the number of new adult websites per day easily outstrips the new proxies/VPN services probably by at least an order of magnitude. The point was if they were already taking the effort to block adult websites, blocking known proxies and VPN services should be relatively trivial.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot block all possible workarounds to access a certain webserver but you may use a layered approach to make it very hard for the average end user to access said blocked content

1. Allow/Block traffic based on destination port(e.g. only allow tcp/80, tcp/443, udp/53)
2. Allow/Block traffic based on destination URL (e.g. block category PORN, Web-Proxy)
3. Allow/Block traffic based on application (e.g. only permit http,https,dns)

A policy as stated above may be implemented by using a modern firewall that is capable of L7 firewalling (e.g. Cisco FirePower, Palo Alto Networks, Checkpoint, Sophos, etc. etc.)

I have only listed a few vendors for reference. There are many solutions for your problem and a firewall capable of deep packet inspection may be the best fit to solve your issue.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. I would also add that each of the 3 options also come with their own set of side effects. So understand what you are doing before implementing them.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to Gadeliow's answer, take a look at Sophos Web Filtering, maybe this is the one you were looking for.

Comment: Product and resource recommendations are off-topic for this very reason. "_Mine is bigger than yours_"

Answer (score 0):

use an anti porn program which will block any porn websites and the program can not be uninstalled without a password that you will set when you setup the program.

link of the program:  http://www.tueagles.com/anti-porn/

Comment: same problem you will face any program like golden shield  or what ever program change proxy settings will tunnel this protection (ya basha)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over network you can use firewall rule allow some block all port that not used this way you can block proxy port based. If using web proxy do not know how to block it except block one by one web proxy or using some service that block web proxy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Block full Internet access to all the use machine IP's in all ports thus it will block direct connectivity to TOR (make sure you blocked tcp port 9001 & 9090 which TOR exit nodes will respond first)
2. Install Bluecoat (I would prefer) or Websense or any other effective proxy server in your network.
3. There will be seperate categorization for we proxies in the name like Proxy Avoidance Category. Block it so that no user could use web proxies
4. In bluecoat if you purchase SSL license, you can intercept https traffic thus ssh to other proxy servers over https can be intercepted and blocked..